# Android attribute of custom type?

Tags: android, xml, inheritance, attributes

I have the following style:

```
<attr name="coloring" format="enum">
    <enum name="Custom" value="0"/>
    <enum name="Black" value="1"/>
    <enum name="Gray" value="2"/>
    <enum name="LightGray" value="3"/>
    <enum name="White" value="4"/>
</attr>
```

I want to apply the same style multiple times like this:

```
 <declare-styleable name="ComplicatedViewGroup">
    <attr name="child1coloring" **format="coloring"**/>
    <attr name="child2coloring" **format="coloring"**/>
    <attr name="child3coloring" **parent="coloring"**/>
    <attr name="child4coloring" **parent="coloring"**/>
    <attr name="child5coloring" **super="coloring"**/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Or something like that. I want to easily be able to customize children views using the same attr. If this isn't possible, this gets *extremely* messy and large, very fast:

```
<attr name="coloring" format="enum">
    <enum name="Custom" value="0"/>
    <enum name="Black" value="1"/>
    <enum name="Gray" value="2"/>
    <enum name="LightGray" value="3"/>
    <enum name="White" value="4"/>
</attr>

 <declare-styleable name="ComplicatedViewGroup">
   <attr name="child1coloring" format="enum">
    <enum name="Custom" value="0"/>
    <enum name="Black" value="1"/>
    <enum name="Gray" value="2"/>
    <enum name="LightGray" value="3"/>
    <enum name="White" value="4"/>
</attr>
    <attr name="child2coloring" format="enum">
    <enum name="Custom" value="0"/>
    <enum name="Black" value="1"/>
    <enum name="Gray" value="2"/>
    <enum name="LightGray" value="3"/>
    <enum name="White" value="4"/>
</attr>
    <attr name="child3coloring" format="enum">
    <enum name="Custom" value="0"/>
    <enum name="Black" value="1"/>
    <enum name="Gray" value="2"/>
    <enum name="LightGray" value="3"/>
    <enum name="White" value="4"/>
</attr>
    <attr name="child4coloring" format="enum">
    <enum name="Custom" value="0"/>
    <enum name="Black" value="1"/>
    <enum name="Gray" value="2"/>
    <enum name="LightGray" value="3"/>
    <enum name="White" value="4"/>
</attr>
    <attr name="child5coloring" format="enum">
    <enum name="Custom" value="0"/>
    <enum name="Black" value="1"/>
    <enum name="Gray" value="2"/>
    <enum name="LightGray" value="3"/>
    <enum name="White" value="4"/>
</attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

Since all these style use the exact same formatting and attributes, I have one function that handles whatever view and coloring value is passed to it. The problem is that I want to be able to add more colors and or functionality. So if I change one, I have to change all of them. This is extremely tedious, and the time it takes to make changes adds up exponentially.

How can I set a parent/super/custom format for an attribute in a declare-styleable?

Answer (score 0):

i think its not necessary to define same attributes multiple times just with different names check this link:
[Define Custom Attributes](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr)